# How can I programmatically scroll in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is a way in SwiftUI to scroll to a view. like this example:

```
ScrollView {

    ScrollViewReader { value in

        Button("Jump to #8") {

            // we scroll on button press
            value.scrollTo(8, anchor: .top)
        }
        .padding()

        ForEach(0..<100) { i in

            Text("Example \(i)")
                .font(.title)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(colors[i % colors.count])
                
                // We need to set ID for scrolling
                .id(i)

        }
    }
}
```

But my UI is not so simple. I have a View and ViewModel. Also some views generated with some delay.

**I need to scroll to some element after all views will be loaded.**

Do it after is not a problem, but how to scroll to needed element programmatically from ViewModel?

---

```
@ObservedObject var model: someViewModel

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ScrollViewReader { pageScroller in

            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Example \(i)")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .background(colors[i % colors.count])
                    .id(i)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 350)
}

class someViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scrollToPageName = 4
    var needToScroll = false

    init() { }
}
```

How to execute `pageScroller.scrollTo(pageIndex, anchor: .top)` from my `model` WITHOUT page refresh?

Or how to execute some view func from model by some event?

Also I need to not do refresh of the page before the scroll(!) - just like on button click from first example.

Comment: Do you want to know how you can scroll and use **pageScroller**?

Comment: @swiftPunk I need to know how to call `pageScroller.scrollTo(pageIndex, anchor: .top)`
 from my `viewModel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the view model's responsibility to scroll, but what you can do is add a `selectedIndex` property to your view model, and observe and react to the change.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ScrollViewReader { pageScroller in
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Example \(i)")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .background(colors[i % colors.count])
                    .id(i)
            }
            .onChange(of: viewModel.selectedIndex) { newIndex in
                pageScroller.scrollTo(newIndex, anchor: .top)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 350)
}
```

Since you mentioned that your content is loaded asynchronously, you can probably update the `selectedIndex` property once everything is loaded.

Comment: great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: is `viewModel.selectedIndex` must be a @Published for a such code?

Comment: It must be! for sure.

Comment: Problem is that this will refresh the window view on change. But I need to do this WITHOUT view refresh. I need something like with a button click from my first sample(it will not do page refresh). Is it possible?

Comment: Normally it would not refresh, I use so much like that, have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It must to refresh page on each model's @Published property change. (if model is Observable/Observed object -- like model must to be)

Comment: then use onReceive, it will solve that issue

Comment: @swiftPunk No it is not. Because of change of any @Published value automatically force `.ObjectWillChange` method call. And it will update the page.

Comment: @Andrew: Maybe you can make a question about it with code that make it happen.

Comment: @swiftPunk I can't because it will not be "Minimal, Reproducible Example" because of I'm using some really specific libraries in my code. All needed information I have already give in my question. And there is already written "Minimal, Reproducible Example".

Comment: @Andrew: As I said I never faced such a issue before, I think it is because of that libraries.

Comment: @swiftPunk This is not an issue. This is as designed behavior of SwiftUI. Please, read the following text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919526/4423545 for understanding basics of work with vievModels in swiftUI

Comment: @swiftPunk I have resolved issue and found solution for all of my problems and you both helped to me, swiftPunk and EmilioPelaez. I will write alternative answer in a few hrs that will work without view refresh.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, marked your comment as an answer, even if it didn't resolve all of my problems. Thanks a lot for your help! It was really-really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT!
This answer will be usefull for you only if it is important to do not make refresh of the view. In another case better to use solution of **EmilioPelaez**

> This answer shows how to:
>
> - send event from model to view
> - and execute some function when event was fired
> - Full view Refresh will be not fired! Only code will be executed just like on button press!

```
@ObservedObject var model: someViewModel

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ScrollViewReader { pageScroller in

            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Example \(i)")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .background(colors[i % colors.count])
                    .id(i)
            }
            //Magic here
            .onReceive(model.scroller.objectWillChange) {
                pageScroller.scrollTo(model.scroller.scrollToPageName, anchor: .top)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 350)
}

class someViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //Magic here
    @ObservedObject var scroller: scrollerHelper

    init() {
        someDelayedCall()
    }

    func someDelayedCall(){
         scroller.scrollToPageName = 8
    }
}

//Magic here
class scrollerHelper: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scrollToPageName: Int = -1
}
```