# Reload SwiftUI view when DateFormatter format updates?

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsdateformatter

Related to [forcing an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561630/swiftui-forcing-an-update), I would like SwiftUI to reload and update my content view when a `DateFormatter` instance's `format` property changes.

Example:

```
private extension String {
  enum TimeDateFormat: String {
    case civilian = "hh:mm a"
    case military = "HH:mm"

    init(is12h: Bool) {
      self = is12h ? .civilian : .military
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  private let formatter = DateFormatter()
  @State private var is24h: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Text(formatter.string(from: .now))

    Button {
      is24h.toggle()
      formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat(is12h: !is24h).rawValue
      // DOESN'T UPDATE THE VIEW
    } label: {
      Text("Toggle format")
    }
  }

  init() {
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat.civilian.rawValue
  }
}
```

I have tried using `Text(Date.now, formatter: formatter)` and that not only does not update the format, `Text(_:formatter:)` does not even apply the format I set in the `ContentView` initializer.

I have also tried reversing the order of the instance property setters.

```
// ...
formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat(is12h: is24h).rawValue
is24h.toggle()
// DOESN'T UPDATE THE VIEW
```

The following code works. However, this code introduces a third instance variable, something I specficaly would like to avoid.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  private let formatter = DateFormatter()
  @State private var is24h: Bool = false
  @State private var text: String

  var body: some View {
    Text(text)

    Button {
      is24h.toggle()
      formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat(is12h: !is24h).rawValue
      text = formatter.string(from: .now)
    } label: {
      Text("Toggle format")
    }
  }

  init() {
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat.civilian.rawValue

    text = formatter.string(from: .now)
  }
}
```

Is there a solution to reload the view without introducing a third variable?

Comment: Put the toggle at the end and use the toggle value in the body. To show the status it should be something in the label of the Button like an on/off indicator. The toggle can only redraw if it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The `@State var is12h` is your source of truth so you want to use that to compute a format depending on its value. If you use the `format:` version of `Text` then SwiftUI will do the formatting for you, e.g.

```
Text(.now, format: .dateTime.hour(.twoDigits(amPM: .wide)).minute(.twoDigits))
    .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: is12h ? "en_GB" : "en_US"))

11:01 PM
23:01
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

```js
struct ContentView: View {
    private let formatter = DateFormatter()
    @State private var is24h: Bool = false
    @State private var formattedDate: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(formattedDate)
            .onChange(of: is24h) { newValue in
                formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat(is12h: !newValue).rawValue
                formattedDate = formatter.string(from: .now)
            }

        Button {
            is24h.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle format")
        }
        .onChange(of: is24h) { _ in }
        .onAppear {
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.dateFormat = .TimeDateFormat.civilian.rawValue
            formattedDate = formatter.string(from: .now)
        }
    }
```